# Is there a better way to combine multiple items in a python list

Tags: python

I've created a function to combine specific items in a python list, but I suspect there is a better way I can't find despite extreme googling. I need the code to be fast, as I'm going to be doing this thousands of times.

**mergeleft** takes a list of items and a list of indices.  In the example below, I call it as mergeleft(fields,(2,4,5)).  Items 5, 4, and 2 of list **fields** will be concatenated to the item immediately to the left.  In this case, **3** and **d** get concatenated to **c**; **b** gets concatenated to **a**.  The result is a list ('ab', 'cd3', 'f').

```
fields = ['a','b','c','d', 3,'f']

def mergeleft(x, fieldnums):
    if 1 in fieldnums: raise Exception('Cannot merge field 1 left')
    if max(fieldnums) > len(x): raise IndexError('Fieldnum {} exceeds available fields {}'.format(max(fieldnums),len(x)))
    y = []
    deleted_rows = ''

    for i,l in enumerate(reversed(x)):
        if (len(x) - i) in fieldnums:
            deleted_rows = str(l) + deleted_rows
        else:
            y.append(str(l)+deleted_rows)
            deleted_rows = ''

    y.reverse()
    return y

print(mergeleft(fields,(2,4,5)))
# Returns ['ab','cd3','f']
```

Comment: Can you explain in word what "mergeleft" should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fields = ['a','b','c','d', 3,'f']
```

This assumes a list of indices in monotonic ascending order.
I reverse the order, so that I'm merging right-to-left.
For each given index, I merge that element into the one on the left, converting to string at each point.
Do note that I've changed the **fieldnums** type to list, so that it's easily reversible.  You can also just traverse the tuple in reverse order.

```
def mergeleft(lst, fieldnums):
    fieldnums.reverse()
    for pos in fieldnums:
        # Merge this field left
        lst[pos-2] = str(lst[pos-2]) + str(lst[pos-1])
        lst = lst[:pos-1] + lst[pos:]

    return lst

print(mergeleft(fields,[2,4,5]))
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'cd3', 'f']
```

Comment: Top notch, many thanks. Frustrated by how quickly you did this after I spent considerably more time trying to think of a better way!!! Python day 2.5, so I'll give myself a bit of slack.

Comment: @TacticalSolutions Notice that this mutates both fields and lst in place.

Comment: @BiRico  Yes, it does.  If that's a problem, it's easily fixed with a copy to local variables.  OP, take note.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decently concise solution, probably among many.

```
def mergeleft(x, fieldnums):
    if 1 in fieldnums: raise Exception('Cannot merge field 1 left')
    if max(fieldnums) > len(x): raise IndexError('Fieldnum {} exceeds available fields {}'.format(max(fieldnums),len(x)))
    ret = list(x)
    for i in reversed(sorted(set(fieldnums))):
        ret[i-1] = str(ret[i-1]) + str(ret.pop(i))
    return ret
```